# CMD Command Copy and paste

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, paste

I want to make a .CMD/.BAT program that copies a cmd command like:

```
title Ipconfig Copy

ipconfig /all

...
```

This program is not completed because I want to copy all information and addresses of command `ipconfig /all` and paste it to notebook.

It is Possible to make it batch?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is redirect the output of the screen to a file, and then optionally open it.

You can do this by using the `>` or `>>` modifier. `>` creates a new file, `>>` appends to a file and creates it if it doesn't already exists.

So your command will be:

```
ipconfig /all >output.txt
notepad output.txt
```

The second line will open the file after it has been completed.

If this is not what you're after, please edit your post and explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to get the data to the clipboard use `clip`  , command clip only get data from txt file:
`clip<yourfile.txt`
[image] 
 or get files with `dir`:
dir|clip
[here](https://www.technorms.com/27347/send-command-prompt-results-clipboard) you can get more about clip.
Then you need to download [paste program](http://www.c3scripts.com/tutorials/msdos/paste.html) you can copy text , cmd  command and file path *[image] after that with `cd` open the folder where you download the `past program` 
[image] 
then either write `paste` or copy it to file
[image] 
and all the thankx to [stackers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819814/how-can-you-get-the-clipboard-contents-with-a-windows-command)
 *no files or photo work here